# Aduino Temperature sensor and led

Tags: arduino

i not have much experience with arduino and need your help . i need switch on / of build in led then temperature rich 27 C . I write scratch but its not work , its read temperature and humidity but led not work , please you help , where is mistake ?

```
#include <dht.h>

dht DHT;

#define DHT11_PIN 2

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
float chk = DHT.read11(DHT11_PIN);
if ( chk > 27.00 )
   digitalWrite( LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
if ( chk < 27.00 )
   digitalWrite( LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
Serial.print("Temperature = ");
Serial.println(DHT.temperature);
Serial.print("Humidity = ");
Serial.println(DHT.humidity);
delay(2000);
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In if you have `chk` which is return value and not temperature. Temperature is in `DHT.temperature` variable. Try this code:

```
#include <dht.h>

dht DHT;

#define DHT11_PIN 2

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  int chk = DHT.read11(DHT11_PIN);
  if ( DHT.temperature > 27.00 )
    digitalWrite( LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  if ( DHT.temperature <= 27.00 )
    digitalWrite( LED_BUILTIN, LOW);

  Serial.print("Temperature = ");
  Serial.println(DHT.temperature);
  Serial.print("Humidity = ");
  Serial.println(DHT.humidity);
  delay(2000);
}
```

Also put `=` to one if to handle `27.00°C` temperature.

Comment: no brother its not work , led is not work , i test led with blink , it is work .

Comment: @xanpx Does DHT11 example work? What can you see in serial monitor?

Comment: yes bro almost , i dont know way if i first check the value to power on or off led and then write to serial its not work

Answer (score 0):

Ok i find the solution , may be its will useful for some one :

```
#include <dht.h>

dht DHT;

#define DHT11_PIN 2

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  int chk = DHT.read11(DHT11_PIN);
  Serial.print("Temperature = ");
  Serial.println(DHT.temperature);
  if ( DHT.temperature > 27.00 )
     digitalWrite( LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  if ( DHT.temperature < 27.00 )
     digitalWrite( LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
  Serial.print("Humidity = ");
  Serial.println(DHT.humidity);
  delay(2000);
```

}